# Can you loop over a comma separated list of values in a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, loops

I need to loop over a comma separated list of IDS that were passed into a stored procedure.  I have seen people use locate() and substring  etc but I haven't seen anything that really makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing that requires pulling the values out of a comma separated list?  Have you googled for a split function?

Comment: looks like I could pass in the length of the comma separated list and use SELECT ELT  to loop over the list.  From what I have read, mysql / relational databases in general are not very good at calculating an occurence of a string, so I think it  would be better to pass in the count, still researching though.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is something like you want? http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=4

Basically it is used to convert a comma delimited string into a table.

Comment: the provide link is now broken